# Detect single key press using key.get_pressed()

Tags: python, pygame, keydown, keyup

I am trying to detect a single key press no matter how long the key is held down. Example, if the 'a' key is held down for 3 seconds, my current program would print this:

key pressed

> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa'

key released

I am trying to get it to where it would only allow a single action per press/release cycle:

key pressed

> 'a'

key released

key pressed

> 'a'

key released

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
def update(self):
    space_released = True
    space_pressed = False

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                self.space_released = True

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                self.space_released = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    while space_released == True:
        # Print key pressed
                return
        space_released = False
```

Comment: You cannot have  `elif` without an `if` that precedes it. And a  `while` with an unconditional `return` statement in it will never iterate more than once. Moreover the indentation of your code is invalid. This code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat) to control how held keys are repeated:

> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple `pygame.KEYDOWN` events. [...]
>
> [...] To disable key repeat call this function with no arguments or with delay set to 0.

Just call `pygame.key.set_repeat()` to disable repeating keys:

```py
pygame.key.set_repeat()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    
    space_released = False
    space_pressed = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                space_released = True

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                space_pressed = True

    # [...]
```

---

If you want to do something similar with `pygame.key.get_pressed ()`, you have to save the state of `pygame.K_SPACE` and compare the previous (`space_was_pressed`) state with the current state (`space_is_pressed`):

```py
space_was_pressed = 0

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    space_released = True
    space_pressed = False
    space_is_pressed = key[pygame.K_SPACE]
    if space_was_pressed != space_is_pressed:
        space_released = not space_is_pressed
        space_pressed = space_is_pressed
    space_was_pressed = space_is_pressed
```